# Can't login to DigitalOcean's droplets after restart

Tags: ssh, ufw

Ubuntu Server 18.04, droplet on DigitalOcean, works many years as a web server. UFW with some usual rules is installed.
Problem: after restarting the server, I can't log in with SSH. There is simply no login prompt, the screen is blank. But - if I than open the Recovery Console (on DigitalOcean), I can log in (as expected). Then I use "ufw disable" and "ufw enable" and log out from Recovery Console.
After that, I can always log in with SSH and work as normal. I can't find anything suspicious in log file.
Any idea what to check?

Comment: Try listing the UFW rules before and after disable/enable, and work out what the differences are, and why.

Comment: Tnx Soren, but all rules are unchanged before/after. I checked the timestamp of files and all are three years old. After I use "ufw disable + ufw enable" in Recovery Console (after restart), everything works fine without problems. 
Maybe one more information - the server has disabled IPv6 network, but my client computes uses IPv6. Can this be a reason for such problem?